# Can I use Bland–Altman plots?

Tags: agreement-statistics, bland-altman-plot

Bland Altman (B.A.) method asses the agreement between two  measurement methods and can evaluate the mean difference (bias) of one method against the "gold standard method."   With the B.A. method we can compute the 95% limits of agreement (not to be confused with confidence bounds).  Would it be appropriate to use this method if I am comparing the difference in my predicted measurements (of my model) to the measured value since I wish to know which points like outside the 95% limits of agreement?

Comment: Many types of residual plots will get you what you are looking for. Why not use those? BA-LoA has some rationale built-in from the perspective that both measurement methods (test and gold-standard) are stochastic observations of the same underlying "metric". Versus, in a typical statistical model, the predicted values are $f(\mathbf{X})$ which are results of a function in which predictor $\mathbf{X}$ inputs are fed into and $\mathbf{y}$ are observations of the response. One more note that BA plots suggest the average of the test and gold-standard readings as the $x$-axis.

Comment: "Bland-Altman" is a standard name especially in biostatistics and medical statistics. All credit to them for many clear discussions in this area, but note that plotting difference versus mean (or sum) is a much older idea.